What are Giants?
I did some research about the Minecraft Giants, and realized they aren't zombies. First off they don't burn in the sun, and second they have the same damage sound that players do. Thirdly, for a short time they used the Steve skin. So my question is, what exactly are they?
Here is a picture from the Minecraft Wiki of a giant next to a normal zombie:


Hi Pengu, welcome to Arqade! What research did you do, and what is it you want to know, exactly? This is not a forum; we like to present factual data, not opinions, so asking what we think about giants is a bit too broad, I'm afraid.

Giants are an unfinished Java Edition mob
As of 1.14, they have no way to spawn naturally, no spawn egg, and no associated AI (i.e. when spawned in using commands, they will not move and cannot chase the player). They have the same texture as a Zombie, but given the unfinished nature of the Giant, its likely this is just a temporary/filler skin.
They have occasionally been given different textures and extra properties in snapshots, however these were reverted when the next major version shipped.
According to the Minecraft Wiki, Notch once stated that the Giants were "too overpowered" but also "too cool to remove".
You can read more on the Minecraft Wiki

Do you need mods to summon giants now?

@Alex no you can summon them using the command /summon minecraft:giant. But they'll just stand there facing south, as they don't have any assigned AI to tell them how to behave

And that is when Behavior Packs would come in handy. That's neat. Technically a big NCP.
